# Java FileReader FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, file-io

I am simply trying to read a file, my class file exist in the exact same directory as the file I'm trying to read. The file I'm trying to read is called `profiles.txt`. I have done the exact same method before In extremely similar circumstances and it worked (and still does work), I have no idea why this doesn't. If anyone could explain I would be very grateful.

```
public static void readProfiles(BST tree) {
        try {
            BufferedReader getData = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(
                            new File("profiles.txt")));

            String data = getData.readLine();

            while(data != null) {
                String[] profileData = data.split(",");
                String[] interests = profileData[7].split(";");
                tree.insertProfile(new Profile(
                        profileData[0],
                        new int[] {Integer.parseInt(profileData[1]), Integer.parseInt(profileData[2]), Integer.parseInt(profileData[3])},
                        profileData[4],
                        profileData[5],
                        profileData[6],
                        interests
                ));
                data = getData.readLine();
            }
            getData.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error occured");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you are using some kind of IDE, sometimes you need to mark the directorie where you have your file stored as the root, worked for me when i had a similar problem using intellij

Comment: Supply a full path to the file. The way it is now the file will need to be within the Project folder (directory) not the **src** folder. You ahould also read your file like this: `String data; while ((data = getData.readLine()) != null) { ....... }`. This eliminates the need for multi reads.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Even when I use the full directory `new File("C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\eclipse-workspace\\Party!\\src\\profiles.txt` it doesn't work.

Comment: And you're sure that the file is named `profiles.txt` and not just `profiles`?

Comment: And not `profiles.txt.txt`?

Comment: Ow my god, how did it take so long to realize this. Who ever posts that comment as an answer first I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The filename is relative and contains no directories, so it needs to be in the current working directory.

Where the class file is has nothing to do it whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, how do I find the current working directory, and how would I change it?

Comment: You are *in* the current working directory when you execute your program. You change it with `cd` or `cwd` according as you are using Windows or not. If you're using an IDE to execute the program, the file needs to be wherever the IDE is when it executes. Where that is depends on the IDE and other things.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: Can't help with that. What is the actual text of the exception?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: profiles.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: In Eclipse, you can set the current working directory in the application launcher.  If you don't, then it depends on where you were when you started Eclipse!

Comment: Eclipse uses the project root of the project that contains the java class with the main method as the cwd

Answer (score -2):

Try the path relative to the main run file of your program.

Comment: The current working directory has nothing to do with the location of any part of the program.